# Git credentials not working on remote node

Tags: git, jenkins

I tried to extend my jenkins master node with another remote machine as executor. I connect the node to the master via `Launch agent by connecting it to the master` (if that matters).

---

My issue are the git credentials. The credentials are defined in Jenkins as global.

The job is a multi branch pipeline.

---

When running the job on the master node, everything works. On the remote node I get

```
using credential correct-id
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://git.domain/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.domain/repo.git/'
```

---

Relevant pipeline step:

```
stage('Checkout Repo') {
            checkout changelog: false,
                    poll: false,
                    scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: params.REPO_BRANCH]],
                          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions:
                                  [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                                    disableSubmodules: false,
                                    parentCredentials: true,
                                    recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                    reference: '',
                                    trackingSubmodules: false]],
                          submoduleCfg: [],
                          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'correct-id', url: 'https://git.domain/repo.git']]]
        }
```

---

My impression was, that the remote node would get the correct credentials via the `credentialsId`.
Is that just wrong? If yes: What use is the `global` then?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Sadly not. We ended up putting the private git RSA key on the node and configure git to use it. That bypassed the whole SCM step. We only needed it for one single node, so that worked fine. I still don't know how to do that via the jenkins credentials. If you find something out I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: I don't know what's up with the credentials but I fixed it by installing the SSH key of the node in out GitLab (where we have a user for Jenkins). I think it is now working regardless of the credentials over the key auth.